# Split string into three columns using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have string like below:

```
rta_geo5: 09/24/14 15:10:38 - Reset_count = 6
rta_geo5: 09/24/14 15:10:38 - restarting
rta_geo5: 09/24/14 15:10:38 - memory allocation: 3500 lines
```

My goal is to split this string into three columns so I can put this into database table:

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------
   | COL1     |      COL 2        | COL 3                        |
    -------------------------------------------------------------
   | rta_geo5 | 09/24/14 15:10:38 |Reset_count = 6               |
    ------------------------------------------------------------- 
   |rta_geo5  | 09/24/14 15:10:38 |restarting                    |
    -------------------------------------------------------------
   | rta_geo5 | 09/24/14 15:10:38 |memory allocation: 3500 lines |
    -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Will be it possible using below statement?

```
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

I just need proper regular expression for that.

Comment: Have you tried to build the pattern yourself? How did it go?

Comment: How do you want to differentiate between `rta_geo5: ` and `allocation: `? What are the strict rules you want to use for the split?

Comment: This looks like it might be fixed width.  If so I'd personally just  pull out the desired substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Split you can use [named groups in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)

pattern:

```
Regex ptrn = new Regex(@"^(?<col1>[^:]+):\s+(?<col2>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+-\s+(?<col3>[^\r\n]+?)\s*$", 
    RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture|RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Usage:

```
string s = @"rta_geo5: 09/24/14 15:10:38 - Reset_count = 6
rta_geo5: 09/24/14 15:10:38 - restarting
rta_geo5: 09/24/14 15:10:38 - memory allocation: 3500 lines";

var matches = ptrn.Matches(s);
```

Accessing:

```
matches.OfType<Match>()
     .Select(match => new string[] 
      { 
         match.Groups["col1"].Value, 
         match.Groups["col2"].Value,
         match.Groups["col3"].Value 
      })
     .ToList().ForEach(a=>System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t|\t",a)));
```

Or:

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            string col1 = match.Groups["col1"].Value;
            string col2 = match.Groups["col2"].Value;
            string col3 = match.Groups["col3"].Value;
            System.Console.WriteLine(col1 + "\t|\t" + col2 + "\t|\t" + col3);
        }
```

output:

```
rta_geo5    |   09/24/14 15:10:38   |   Reset_count = 6
rta_geo5    |   09/24/14 15:10:38   |   restarting
rta_geo5    |   09/24/14 15:10:38   |   memory allocation: 3500 lines
```

Answer (score 0):

split on this:

```
(?:(?<=geo5):\s|(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s-\s)
```

demo here :

http://regex101.com/r/xF7iD7/1

Answer (score 0):

I would not use regex (or String.Split) for this but a loop where you parse each line. I would also use a custom class to map to the database table to increase redability and reusability.

The class (simplified):

```
public class Data
{
    public string Token1 { get; set; } // use a meaningful name
    public string Token2 { get; set; } // use a meaningful name
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } // use a meaningful name

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Token1:[{0}] Date:[{1}] Token2:[{2}]", 
            Token1,
            Date.ToString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
            Token2);
    }
}
```

Your sample string:

```
string data = @"rta_geo5: 09/24/14 15:10:38 - Reset_count = 6
rta_geo5: 09/24/14 15:10:38 - restarting
rta_geo5: 09/24/14 15:10:38 - memory allocation: 3500 lines";
```

Now you can use this loop using plain string-methods to parse the text to a `List<Data>`:

```
string[] lines = data.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
List<Data> allData = new List<Data>();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string token1 = null, token2 = null;
    DateTime dt;
    int firstColonIndex = line.IndexOf(": ");
    if (firstColonIndex >= 0)
    {
        token1 = line.Remove(firstColonIndex);
        firstColonIndex += 2; // start next search after first token to find DateTime
        int indexOfMinus = line.IndexOf(" - ", firstColonIndex);
        if (indexOfMinus >= 0)
        {
            string datePart = line.Substring(firstColonIndex, indexOfMinus - firstColonIndex);
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(datePart, "MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
            {
                indexOfMinus += 3;  // start next search after DateTime to get last token
                token2 = line.Substring(indexOfMinus);
                Data d = new Data { Token1 = token1, Token2 = token2, Date = dt };
                allData.Add(d);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
foreach (Data d in allData)
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());

Token1:[rta_geo5] Date:[09/24/14 15:10:38] Token2:[Reset_count = 6]
Token1:[rta_geo5] Date:[09/24/14 15:10:38] Token2:[restarting]
Token1:[rta_geo5] Date:[09/24/14 15:10:38] Token2:[memory allocation: 3500 lines]
```

This approach is more verbose but more efficient/maintainable than others. It also allows to log abnormalities or to use other methods to parse it.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong but on my PC output looks like:
row1: Token1:[data1] Date:[date] Token2:[data2
row2: data3 date data3]

Comment: @ironcurtain: i don't know. Have you used his sample data (`string data = @ ...`)? I've tested the code again and it correctly shows  the result above. What does your string[] `lines` contain? Have you copy-pasted the line-breaks?

Comment: I think there was an issue, because the string was retrieved from UNIX system and as I checked some lines didn't have break lines. I decided to copy the files to local machine and then split the columns. I didn't test you solution but I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, had a think about this, not sure if this is 100%, but try:

`(rta_geo5): (.*?) - (.*)`

Should split it into 3 groups as required. However, it assumes that the leading identifier is always `(rta_geo5)`.

**[edit]** -I notice one of the answers refs the online regex service, so you could try using my regex inside that: http://regex101.com/r/xF7iD7/1 (sorry, don't have an account there yet -but will create right now) -also, regards the rta_geo5 block, you could of course go completely *native* with

`(.*): (.*) - (.*)`

see how it works either way